# Request: Efficient procedure to manually loop between two lists in python

Tags: python, nested-loops, key-bindings

I feel really silly asking this but I have been struggling for a couple of days on how to 
improve my code and I cannot discern the obvious way to improve the actual design which is rather inefficient and ugly despite its supposed simplicity...

I need to move across a couple of lists using key events.

For simplicity's sake let's say that the first list is “Shops” and the second one is “Products”

Shops = [ShopA,ShopB,ShopC,ShopcD,ShopE]

Products = [Oranges, Milk, Water, Chocolate, Rice]

Let's say that with the keyboards keys “1” and “2”  I want to move forward and backward respectively along the “Shops” list. On the other hand, I want to use keys “3” and “4” to move  forward and backward respectively on the “Products” list.

Now, the method I have consists in a couple of  counters: The “ShopCounter” and the “ProductsCounter”. Incidentally, each time I move along the “Shops” list I set the “ProductsCounter” to zero so it can start at the checking at the first item (in this example that would be the oranges :)

My problem lies now in the location/design of the counters. I have four sections in this code: One for each key instruction I want as and input (Next/Previous Shop; Next/Previous Product).

Since python starts the lists at zero the obvious reason would be to place the counters at the end of each code section. However, if I do this I must press twice each key a backward/forward key if the previous command was a forward/backward. Since it preserves the increased counter from the previous command

If I put the counters at the beginning of each section (which makes each section more... easier to understand...) I have to set an “if” check to make sure the code does not overcome the first items on the list. Also following this design, I must check an additional if check to make sure it does not try to find an item beyond the list length...

Any advice on the right way to handle these kind of operations??  It would be most welcome.

Edit:

This code represents the example I have provided with the structure I would like to change. It works, I just think there should be a way to do this in a more logical way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def CounterManager(Key, ShopNumber, ProductsNumber, ShopsStarterCheck, ProductsStarterCheck, ShopsCounter, ProductsCounter):

    if Key == "1" or Key == "2":

        ProductsCounter = 0

        if ShopsCounter == 0 and ShopsStarterCheck == True:
            ShopsStarterCheck = False
            print "eo"

        elif Key == "1" :        
            ShopsCounter =  ShopsCounter + 1        
        elif Key == "2" :        
            ShopsCounter =  ShopsCounter - 1

        if  ShopsCounter <= 0:
            ShopsCounter = 0      
        if  ShopsCounter >= ShopNumber - 1:
            ShopsCounter = ShopNumber - 1

        ProductsStarterCheck = True
        print "--Shop: " + str(ShopsCounter)

    if Key == "3" or Key == "4":

        if ProductsCounter == 0 and ProductsStarterCheck == True:
            ProductsStarterCheck = False           
        elif Key == "3" :        
            ProductsCounter =  ProductsCounter + 1
        elif Key == "4" :        
            ProductsCounter =  ProductsCounter - 1          

        if  ProductsCounter <= 0:
            ProductsCounter = 0
        if  ProductsCounter >= ProductsNumber - 1:
            ProductsCounter = ProductsNumber - 1
        print "--Product: " + str(ProductsCounter)

    return ShopNumber, ProductsNumber, ShopsStarterCheck, ProductsStarterCheck, ShopsCounter, ProductsCounter

def Key_Manager(event):

    global ShopNumber, ProductsNumber, ShopsStarterCheck, ProductsStarterCheck, ShopsCounter, ProductsCounter

    if event.key == '1' or event.key == '2':
        ShopNumber, ProductsNumber, ShopsStarterCheck, ProductsStarterCheck, ShopsCounter, ProductsCounter = CounterManager(event.key, ShopNumber, ProductsNumber, ShopsStarterCheck, ProductsStarterCheck, ShopsCounter, ProductsCounter)
        print Shops[ShopsCounter]


    if event.key == '3' or event.key == '4':
        ShopNumber, ProductsNumber, ShopsStarterCheck, ProductsStarterCheck, ShopsCounter, ProductsCounter = CounterManager(event.key, ShopNumber, ProductsNumber, ShopsStarterCheck, ProductsStarterCheck, ShopsCounter, ProductsCounter)
        print Products[ProductsCounter]

Shops = ["ShopA","ShopB","ShopC","ShopD","ShopE"]
Products = ["Oranges", "Milk", "Water", "Chocolate", "Rice"]

ShopNumber, ProductsNumber = len(Shops), len(Products)
ShopsStarterCheck,ProductsStarterCheck = True,True
ShopsCounter,ProductsCounter, = 0,0

Fig1=plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
Axis1 = Fig1.add_subplot(111)
Fig_Connection = {}
Fig_Connection['cid'] = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',Key_Manager)     #Create figure an connect the event to it

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show some code you've tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: Thank you for your interest Mike, I have written a code following the example I gave but with the structre I would like to change. It works, I just think it is not the right way to design it (I am fairly new to python)